# Relabel a matrix, replacing all unique numbers with 1..N

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I'm using MATLAB. I have a matrix with `N` elements filled with numbers `[1; N]`, but there are only `K` unique number between them (`K` is much less than `N`). What is an *efficient* way to relabel the matrix so that it contains only numbers `[1; K]`? Equal numbers should become equal, and not equal should become not equal.

Example for `N = 10`, `K = 4`:

```
[1 4 8 9 4 1 8 9 4 1] -> [1 2 3 4 2 1 3 4 2 1]
```

- N ~ 1 000 000
- K ~ 10 000

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the third output argument of `unique`:

```
a=[1 4 8 9 4 1 8 9 4 1];
[~, ~, b] = unique(a)
b =
     1     2     3     4     2     1     3     4     2     1
```

Comment: Just realised this won't work if you have NaNs in your input, as `unique` will assign them all different numbers. Maybe that's not an issue in your case, though.

Comment: Yes, this is not an issue for me.